Understanding Canonical-embedding vs Coefficient-embedding in Ideal Lattices: Relation to NTT?
I'm trying to understand the relationship between different representations of ideal lattices, particularly the canonical embedding and coefficient embedding. While studying these concepts, I noticed some similarities between:

Canonical embedding vs coefficient embedding
NTT form vs normal polynomial form

Is there a meaningful relationship between these concepts? Specifically:

Can we think of canonical embedding as being analogous to NTT form, since both transform the representation and allow component-wise operations?
Is coefficient embedding essentially the same as the normal polynomial form?
What are the key differences that make this analogy incomplete or incorrect?

I understand that:

Canonical embedding uses complex embeddings
NTT works in finite fields
Both allow certain operations to be done component-wise
Both are transformations from a coefficient representation

But I'm struggling to understand how these concepts relate to each other in the bigger picture of lattice-based cryptography.
Could someone explain the relationships and differences between these representations, particularly focusing on their roles in cryptographic applications? While implementation details often use NTT for efficiency, theoretical analysis seems to prefer working with canonical embeddings, and I'm trying to bridge this gap in my understanding.
